# Flyway test cases - SmallTests vs. MediumTests

Tags: flyway

I created some new test cases on a couple of new features I would like to request for addition to Flyway. These features are mainly changes to the Flyway class. However, there seems to be two unit test categories, SmallTests and MediumTests. Is there some sort of criteria for determining which one my test cases should fall under?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. These are based on the test categories described by the Google Testing Blog: http://googletesting.blogspot.de/2010/12/test-sizes.html

But make sure raise issues for your fixes and discuss them first to avoid doing work for nothing.